# Send password as encrypted to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a ticketing help desk and I want to edit my users' passwords. But the passwords are encrypted in database like this : `$2a$08$IdljRhapMTPYzdB0l4t/AuHatF8imyNREH.yKtBZelmVJAi5Sa/c.`
I want to change the password in my help desk `user_edit.php` file and enter password field like this: `password@123` and the server automatically encrypt it.

Comment: Why do you need to "edit" user passwords.... setting a new password doesn't require you to "decrypt"

Comment: You only need to update a password, not edit it.

Comment: How are the passwords getting encrypted righjt now? Which algorithm or procedure is used ?

Comment: Ok so you want to encrypt password from the database?? If yes then you need to use the trigger

Comment: @SQLPolice - with `$2a$08$` it's Blowfish, with a cost of 8

Comment: i want to enter a normal password in my help desk user_edit section and the server save the encrypted password

Comment: Yes, so if you're resetting a users password, then you enter a new password and send that to the server which hashes and stores it.... what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite an unsafe solution, you should instead think of updating password. If needed, first encrypt it and than compare to the elder one to know if the user haven't typed the same password, which is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find and reuse the code of the system that has created those passwords, or encrypts user entry as part of login.

For security you should encrypt passwords "one way". For logins you take the plain text input of the password, encrypt that in the same way that the password was originally and compare the encrypted texts, to see whether they are the same.

Find and reuse this encryption to add a new password.to your user.